# Multiple Fetch Requests within an onchange function

Tags: javascript

I have 3 dropdown menus, and I am trying to populate 2 of the dropdowns based on the selection of the first. If I select a client from my list, then I want my second dropdown to show all sites that the client has and the third dropdown to show all the contacts from that client.

Currently, I can get one or the other working, but not both together. An example of getting one wokring is:

```
let site_select = document.getElementById('sites');
let client_select = document.getElementById('client');

client_select.onchange = function() {
    client = client_select.value;
    
    fetch('/client-sites/' + client).then(function(response) {
        response.json().then(function(data) {
            let optionHTML = '';
            for (let csite of data.client_sites){
                optionHTML += '<option value="' + csite.id + '">' + csite.name + '</option>';
            }
            site_select.innerHTML = optionHTML;
        });
    });
}
```

This will find all sites associated with my selected client. But when I try to add in contacts then they both don't complete.

I tried adding the following:

```
let site_select = document.getElementById('sites');
let contact_select = document.getElementById('client_contact');
let client_select = document.getElementById('client');

client_select.onchange = function() {
    client = client_select.value;
    
    fetch('/client-sites/' + client).then(function(response) {
        response.json().then(function(data) {
            let optionHTML = '';
            for (let csite of data.client_sites){
                optionHTML += '<option value="' + csite.id + '">' + csite.name + '</option>';
            }
            site_select.innerHTML = optionHTML;
        });
    });
}

client_select.onchange = function() {
    client = client_select.value;
    
    fetch('/contacts/' + client).then(function(response) {
        response.json().then(function(data) {
            let optionHTML = '';
            console.table(data)
            for (let con of data.contacts){
                optionHTML += '<option value="' + con.id + '">' + con.name + '</option>';
            }
            contact_select.innerHTML = optionHTML;
        });
    });
}
```

I also tried creating the same but with:

```
let client_select2 = document.getElementById('client');
client_select2.onchange = function() {...
```

and I tried doubling up the fetches:

```
let site_select = document.getElementById('sites');
let contact_select = document.getElementById('client_contact');
let client_select = document.getElementById('client');

client_select.onchange = function() {
    client = client_select.value;
    
    fetch('/client-sites/' + client).then(function(response) {
        response.json().then(function(data) {
            let optionHTML = '';
            for (let csite of data.client_sites){
                optionHTML += '<option value="' + csite.id + '">' + csite.name + '</option>';
            }
            site_select.innerHTML = optionHTML;
        });
    });

    fetch('/contacts/' + client).then(function(response) {
        response.json().then(function(data) {
            let optionHTML = '';
            console.table(data)
            for (let con of data.contacts){
                optionHTML += '<option value="' + con.id + '">' + con.name + '</option>';
            }
            contact_select.innerHTML = optionHTML;
        });
    });
}
```

Looking into promise.all(), that looked like something that could work, but I was not sure how to use it. Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: A very ugly, but very quick solution would be to copy&paste code for the second fetch immediately after the `site_select.innerHTML = optionHTML;` line. Joëssel's answer is much cleaner, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you redefine client_select.onchange, your will only have one in the end. Unless you have the need to support old version of IE, I would advise to use addEventListenner.

I think that Promise.all is the way to go there:

```
let site_select = document.getElementById('sites');
let contact_select = document.getElementById('client_contact');
let client_select = document.getElementById('client');

const fetchClientSites = (client) => {
  return fetch('/client-sites/' + client)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(function(data) {
      let optionHTML = '';

      for (let csite of data.client_sites) {
        optionHTML += '<option value="' + csite.id + '">' + csite.name + '</option>';
      }

      site_select.innerHTML = optionHTML;
    });
};

const fetchContacts = (client) => {
  return fetch('/contacts/' + client)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(function(data) {
      let optionHTML = '';

      for (let con of data.contacts) {
        optionHTML += '<option value="' + con.id + '">' + con.name + '</option>';
      }

      contact_select.innerHTML = optionHTML;
    });
};

client_select.addEventListener('change', () => {
  const client = client_select.value;

  Promise.all(
    fetchClientSites(client),
    fetchContacts(client),
  );
});
```

Comment: the addEventListener looking for the change was what I was completely missing. That worked perfectly for my needs. Thank you!